# Blank page when deploying app with Cloud Storage and custom domain

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-storage, custom-domain

I am running into an issue when trying to deploy a React website using Google Cloud Storage and a custom domain name.

1. I build my react app locally using `npm run build`.
2. Upload the build folder to a bucket with the name [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). Upload a yaml that contains:

```
runtime: nodejs10
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html

  - url: /
    static_dir: build
```

3. Open cloud shell
4. run `gsutil rsync -r gs://www.example.com ./example`
5. run  `cd ./example`
6. run `gcloud app deploy`
7. The app works great at the `https://example-dot-projectname.uc.r.appspot.com` url
8. The app is a blank page at the [www.mycustomdomain.com](http://www.mycustomdomain.com)
9. The console reads `Loading failed for the <script> with source "http://www.mycustomdomain.com/static.js/###.chunk.js"` twice
10. I also ran `gsutil web set -m build/index.html gs://www.example.com` and it did not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`?

Comment: I think this could be a code issue or misconfiguration, check for configuration strings that should be pointing to `www.mycustomdomain.com`. perhaps a route is not properly configured to be pointing to the domain, there really shouldn't be any reason why a custom domain is not running the app. Are you able to open the URL `http://www.mycustomdomain.com/static.js/###.chunk.js`? Does it give a not found 404? or something else?